# Android CookieManager.setCookie doesn't sync across different process?

Tags: android, cookies, android-service, android-cookiemanager

In Android, we can have [different process (e.g. a Service in another process)](https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/life-beyond-android-application-ed1f59058e58?sk=46fb1059955af754b72aea5a5946cfee).

However, I notice the CookieManager (from android.webkit.CookieManager) doesn't sync its newly set Cookie across the process.

I have a function in the MainActivity that set the Cookie

```
cookieManager.setCookie(url, cookieString)
cookieManager.flush()
```

If I read it in the MainActivity or MainService (service in the same process), then I can get it read.

```
val cookie = cookieManager.getCookie(url)
```

However, if I read it in the OtherService (service in the other process), then it might not get it.

To demonstrate this clearly, I have created an App as shown below. You can get the [code here](https://github.com/elye/issue_android_cookie_manager_not_sync_across_process)

[image]

**1. Freshly Install App**

1. Install a freshly created App
2. Click Main Process Service: Log (TrackingMe) shows no Cookie Set <*Correct*>
3. Click Other Process Service: Log (TrackingMe) shows no Cookie Set <*Correct*>
4. Click Write Cookie to write cookie into CookieManager
5. Click Main Process Service: Log (TrackingMe) shows Cookie Set <*Correct*>
6. Click Other Process Service: Log (TrackingMe) shows no Cookie Set <***Incorrect***>

**2. Kill the App and Restart the App**

1. Kill and Restart the App (don't remove the App data)
2. Click Main Process Service: Log (TrackingMe) shows Cookie Set <*Correct*>
3. Click Other Process Service: Log (TrackingMe) shows Cookie Set <*Correct*>
4. Click Clear Cookie to clear all Cookies into CookieManager
5. Click Main Process Service: Log (TrackingMe) shows no Cookie Set <*Correct*>
6. Click Other Process Service: Log (TrackingMe) shows Cookie Set <***Incorrect***>

The finding

- The Other Process Service will not get the updated cookies from the CookieManager. It can only get it after the App is killed and restart.

The question:

- How can we get the Other Process Service get the Cookies from the CookieManager immediately? (without need to restart the App?)

Comment: I suspect this is a Google Bug, and reported here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/185420715